# Django Apache mod_wsgi permission errors

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Have setup Django in virtualenv but get 500 Internal Server Error. Development server worked fine.

### Environment:

- Python 2.7.12
- Apache 2.4.23
- Django 1.10
- Fedora 24

### Server log:

```
[Mon Aug 29 12:27:49.364393 2016] [mime_magic:error] [pid 19158] [client 14.2.108.225:49222] AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read `/home/fedora/motorable/motorable/wsgi.py'
[Mon Aug 29 12:27:49.364552 2016] [mime_magic:error] [pid 19158] [client 14.2.108.225:49222] AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read `/home/fedora/motorable/motorable/wsgi.py'
[Mon Aug 29 12:27:49.364904 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 19157] (13)Permission denied: [remote 14.2.108.225:1832] mod_wsgi (pid=19157, process='motorable', application='ip-172-31-22-170.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal|'): Call to fopen() failed for '/home/fedora/motorable/motorable/wsgi.py'.
```

### Configuration:

```
Alias /static /home/fedora/motorable/static
<Directory /home/fedora/motorable/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/fedora/motorable/motorable>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess motorable python-path=/home/fedora/motorable:/home/fedora/mot$
WSGIProcessGroup motorable
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/fedora/motorable/motorable/wsgi.py
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
```

WSGI is running in daemon mode, I tried adding the `WSGISocketPrefix` directive but I'm not sure what else to check or do. First time experimenting with Django here. The user home directory is 710 and should allowing Apache in, I added apache user to the primary group of fedora.

Can anyone share some insight?

Comment: check the permissions on wsgi.py.

Comment: Offtopic, but if `First time experimenting with Django here` you should know that you can also use `uwsgi` , here is about how to connect `uWSGI` + `Django` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/ and here how `Apache` + `uWSGI` http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Apache.html

Comment: wsgi.py is set 664 but I did chown to the web server group and still nothing.
@user3479125 I'm not sure if another interface module will address the underlying problem.

Comment: Not execute calling as file, rejected by apache ! Where `exec defitions` ?

Comment: Are you running SELinux? Is your home directory permissions such that others cannot read/search it?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton SE Linux is enabled and my home directory permissions are drwx--x--- (0710).

Comment: Both will likely prevent Apache being able to see inside of your home directory. It can't therefore load the WSGI script file. Move your project out of your home directory under something like ``/var/www/motorable``.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the project outside the home directory to /var/www/django solved my question.